# pointwise limit of uniformly bounded sequence in $A(\mathbb T)$ is again in $A(\mathbb T)$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathbb T$ be a circle group, and $\hat{f}(n)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt;$ $(n\in \mathbb Z, f\in L^{1} (\mathbb T)).$
Put $A(\mathbb T)= \{f\in C(\mathbb T): \hat{f}\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z), \  \text{that is}, \  \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty \}. $
$A(\mathbb T)$ is normed by 
$$\|f\|=\|f\|_{A(\mathbb T)}= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)|; (f\in A(\mathbb T)).$$
Suppose $f_{n} \in A(\mathbb T), \ \|f_{n}\|\leq M,$ (Fix, $M>0$)
$$f(y)= \lim_{n\to \infty} f_{n} (y), (y\in \mathbb T)$$
and $f$ is continuous.

> **My Question is**: Can we expect,  $f\in A(\mathbb T)$ and $\|f\|\leq M$ ?

(If answer is positive, and proof is long, proper reference also will be o.k for me;)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $n$ for indices of two kinds is evil. I rename $f_n$ as $f_k$.

Since $\sup_{\mathbb T} |f| \le \|f\|_{A(\mathbb T)}$, the sequence $(f_k)$ is uniformly bounded. The dominated convergence theorem implies $f_k\to f$ in $L^1$. Therefore, for every $n$ we have $\hat {f_k}(n)\to \hat f(n)$ as $k\to\infty$. By Fatou's lemma, $$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat f(n)| \le \liminf_{k\to\infty} \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat {f_k}(n)| \le M$$

Comment: @146912; Thanks a lot;but would you please tell me why, $\sup_{t\in \mathbb T} |f(t)| \leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)| $ ? ; thanks again ?

Comment: Also, at priory, we do not know $\|f\|_{A(\mathbb T)}$ is finite; and so my confusion is, how the estimate, $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \|f\|_{A(\mathbb T)}$ is helpful ?